# Array of array of prime factors in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, prime-factoring

I was wondering if anyone could think of a way to create an array or arrays of prime factors, and filter it down to only the number of factors needed to create all the numbers in a set.

For instance, the numbers `1-16`, would have an array set like :

`[ [2,2,2,2], [3,3], [5], [7], [11], [13] ]`

Comment: Best of luck doing this in any efficient way. If you manage it though, you've just cracked the world's most relied upon encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this working without the break through @christopher mentions in his comment is to factor every number in the set (an expensive operation). If you set up some kind of array to accumulate prime factors, each time you factor a number, check the array to make sure it contains all those factors. And, as you pointed out in your questions, you need to check that you have ENOUGH of a particular factor (your question notes that 1-16 would require 4 2's).

Comment: Well now I have a moral dilemma.